# iOS cannot convert [String:Any?] to [String] How to convert?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode

I'm rushing a project and am not able to research to find the answer. I hope I can get some help on this.

```
var tt: Array<[String:Any]> = []
var forpickarray: [String] = []
```

Error: cannot convert [String:Any?] to [String]

```
for index in 1...self.tt.count {
     var arr: [String] = self.tt[index-1]
     forpickarray.append(self.tt[index-1])                    
}
```

I am trying to get the value- Just the listname

```
[["total": 2, "listName": Testing, "listid": 1], ["total": 1, "listName": Yeeea, "listid": 2]]
```

Comment: What do you want the output to be from you array of dictionaries? I'm still trying to work out what you're actually asking. Haha :D

Comment: Bro, you're trying to assign a dictionary in and array of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, just seen your edit. Helps a lot.

To get the value of the `listName` from each dictionary you can do like this...

```
forPickArray = tt.flatMap { $0["listName"] }
```

Rename your variables to have sensible names. `tt` is not a sensible name. I have no idea what it is :D

Comment: Thanks! But i m trying to get the value. I updated the qn

Answer (score 1):

within your for-loop, are you trying to extract keys from the dictionary and convert it to an array? then you need to do the following:

```
var arr: [String] = Array(tt[index-1].keys)
forpickarray.append(contentsOf: arr)
```

Because `tt` is an array of dictionary, each element in `tt` could have many keys

Comment: Thanks! But i m trying to get the value. I updated the qn

Answer (score 1):

Please use native Swift syntax rather than ugly *Objective-cish* code.

A loop is not needed at all:

```
forpickarray = tt.flatMap{ $0["listName"] as? String }
```

Even if a loop was required there is a much more efficient way than a (zero!)index-based `for` loop:

```
for item in tt {
    forpickarray.append(item)
}
```